# Activate class on div click

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I found some interesting program that creates a card and then turn it backwards when hover and here is the css.

```
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
#team {
    background: #eee !important;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus {
    background-color: #108d6f;
    border-color: #108d6f;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007b5e;
    border-color: #007b5e;
}

section {
    padding: 60px 0;
}

section .section-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #007b5e;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#team .card {
    border: none;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.image-flip:hover .backside,
.image-flip.hover .backside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.image-flip:hover .frontside,
.image-flip.hover .frontside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.mainflip {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.frontside {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.backside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
    box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
}

.frontside,
.backside {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.frontside .card,
.backside .card {
    min-height: 312px;
}

.backside .card a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #007b5e !important;
}

.frontside .card .card-title,
.backside .card .card-title {
    color: #007b5e !important;
}

.frontside .card .card-body img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

and this is the part of the html where the css works.

```
    <section id="team" class="pb-5">
        <div class="container">
            <h5 class="section-title h1">OUR TEAM</h5>
            <div class="row">

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Team member -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="image-flip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                        <div class="mainflip">
                            <div class="frontside">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <p><img class=" img-fluid" src="https://sunlimetech.com/portfolio/boot4menu/assets/imgs/team/img_01.png" alt="card image"></p>
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Sunlimetech</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="backside">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body text-center mt-4">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Sunlimetech</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.</p>
                                        <ul class="list-inline">
                                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- ./Team member -->
</section>
```

my question is how can i activate the class that turns the div backwards on div click?

I mean when the div is in forward look and i clicked it it will turn backward and when i click the div again it will turn at front.

I tried many changes but still not work thnx

Comment: There is no `text-xs-center` in Bootstrap 4. Or `col-xs`.

Comment: sorry if there is not but when i checked it is already there and here is the link of css `<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">`

Comment: The classes are incorrect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change all the hover properties to a new class and use jquery toggleClass method to add and remove the class on click. Because :hover property will get triggered when you place your mouse over that element. If you want it on clicking, then you have to bind the hovering action to click action.

In the provided example i have created new class with hovering properties and gave to the click action.

```js
        $(document).ready(function()
                         {
           
            $('.image-flip').click(function()
                                  {
               $(this).toggleClass('image-fliper'); 
            });
            
        });
```

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
#team {
    background: #eee !important;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus {
    background-color: #108d6f;
    border-color: #108d6f;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007b5e;
    border-color: #007b5e;
}

section {
    padding: 60px 0;
}

section .section-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #007b5e;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#team .card {
    border: none;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.image-fliper .backside,
.image-fliper .backside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.image-fliper .frontside,
.image-fliper .frontside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.mainflip {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
}

.frontside {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.backside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
    box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
}

.frontside,
.backside {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.frontside .card,
.backside .card {
    min-height: 312px;
}

.backside .card a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #007b5e !important;
}

.frontside .card .card-title,
.backside .card .card-title {
    color: #007b5e !important;
}

.frontside .card .card-body img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="team" class="pb-5">
        <div class="container">
            <h5 class="section-title h1">OUR TEAM</h5>
            <div class="row">

            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <!-- Team member -->
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="image-flip" ontouchstart="this.classList.toggle('hover');">
                        <div class="mainflip">
                            <div class="frontside">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body text-center">
                                        <p><img class=" img-fluid" src="https://sunlimetech.com/portfolio/boot4menu/assets/imgs/team/img_01.png" alt="card image"></p>
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Sunlimetech</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.</p>
                                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="backside">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-body text-center mt-4">
                                        <h4 class="card-title">Sunlimetech</h4>
                                        <p class="card-text">This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.</p>
                                        <ul class="list-inline">
                                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item">
                                                <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                                                    <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                                                </a>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: @NardongBagsik are you saying the style is not coming properly or the code is not working?

Comment: the code is not working sir and also please check my edited html i include the whole body's section

Comment: What do you think? I try to reedit it but still not working

Comment: Check the new answer let me whether it solved your problem or not?

Comment: sir can i ask you something?

Comment: in case i click 1 div it will turn backward and if i click other div. the others will return back to its original front state

Comment: Same code before the $(this).toggleClass('image-fliper'); add $('.image-flip').remove class('image-fliper')

Answer (score 1):

```css
@import url('https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css');
#team {
    background: #eee !important;
}

.btn-primary:hover,
.btn-primary:focus {
    background-color: #108d6f;
    border-color: #108d6f;
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}

.btn-primary {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #007b5e;
    border-color: #007b5e;
}

section {
    padding: 60px 0;
}

section .section-title {
    text-align: center;
    color: #007b5e;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

#team .card {
    border: none;
    background: #ffffff;
}
/*
.mainflip:hover .backside,
.image-flip:hover .backside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}

.mainflip:hover .frontside,
.mainflip:hover .frontside {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}*/

.mainflip {
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transform: perspective(1000px);
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    position: relative;
    margin:15px;
    display:inline-block
}

input[type="checkbox"]{
  opacity:0
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .backside {
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    border-radius: .25rem;
}


input[type="checkbox"]:checked+label .frontside{
      -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
    transform: rotateY(180deg);
}



.frontside {
    position: relative;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(0deg);
    z-index: 2;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.backside {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: white;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -ms-transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
    box-shadow: 5px 7px 9px -4px rgb(158, 158, 158);
}

.frontside,
.backside {
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
    -ms-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: 1s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}





.frontside .card,
.backside .card {
    min-height: 312px;
}

.backside .card a {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #007b5e !important;
}

.frontside .card .card-title,
.backside .card .card-title {
    color: #007b5e !important;
}

.frontside .card .card-body img {
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<input id="activeClas" name="activeClas" type="checkbox"/>
<label for="activeClas" class="mainflip">
    <div class="frontside">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center">
                <p><img class=" img-fluid" src="https://sunlimetech.com/portfolio/boot4menu/assets/imgs/team/img_02.png" alt="card image"></p>
                <h4 class="card-title">Sunlimetech</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.</p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    

    <div  class="backside">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-body text-center mt-4">
                <h4 class="card-title">Sunlimetech</h4>
                <p class="card-text">This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.This is basic card with image on top, title, description and button.</p>
                <ul class="list-inline">
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-skype"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="list-inline-item">
                        <a class="social-icon text-xs-center" target="_blank" href="#">
                            <i class="fa fa-google"></i>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</label>
```

This is without any JS, and hope as per your requirement. when the div is in forward look and i clicked it it will turn backward and when i click the div again it will turn at front. Its working fine for me, If not as per you want , pls let know.